# How to set font size for different screen size in webapp created by react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, screen

I'm making web-app using react-native. But stuck on font-size for different screen-size.

How can I change the different font-size for different screen resolution?

Comment: Can you share the screen you are trying achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`Dimension` from 'react-native' gives you access to the device dimensions. You could use these to set fontSize conditionally.

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("screen").height;
```

How you use these to set the fontSize would be up to you.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a react-native package for handle the responsiveness of
> fonts and hight , width also

> Package name:

```
npm i react-native-responsive-screen
```